# How to get a guild by id with Discord Rest API

Tags: node.js, api, rest, discord

I want get a specific discord guild by id for test if my user has permissions to add bot on them guild.

I try with `https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/guilds` and params `before` and `after`.
But id is snowflake/string and I use nodeJs so it's not possible do : -1.

My current code :

```js
const id = "XXXXXXXXXXX",
      before = id + 1,  // don't work because it's string and big int
      after = id - 1    // same
;

const url = `https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/guilds?before=${before}&after=${after}`;


fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXX",
    }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json));
```

Idea ? Thank you.

Comment: can you postyour code  or what did you tried?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra sorry, I edit my post with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### You should use `/guilds/{your guild id here}`. This fetches JSON data for a specific guild.

If you would like to find the permissions of the User, try `/guilds/{your guild id here}/member/{user}`

#### Examples

Finding a guild:

```js
const id = "REPLACE_THIS_WITH_YOUR_GUILD",
const url = `https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/`+id;


fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bot XXXXXXXXXXX",
    }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json));
```

Finding a guild member:

```js
const id = "XXXXXXXXXXX",
const member = '0000000000'
const url = `https://discord.com/api/v9/guild/${id}/member/${member}`;


fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "Bot XXXXXXXXXXX",
    }
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(json => console.log(json));
```